# What is your experience of PHP encrypters? Which one would you recommend?

Tags: php, deployment, encryption

We have an application that is written in PHP that we are going to license to a customer. Our company believes that the customer might intend to steal the source code and create their own fork of the software, therefore we want to encrypt the source code.

I have searched some for PHP-encrypters and found several that seems good, but since we have no previous experience of PHP-encrypters it hard to say which one is the best. Which PHP encrypters have you used and what is your experience?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232736/code-obfuscator-for-php, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/698320/what-is-the-best-php-code-encryptor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, First:

> It is impossible to encrypt your entire code base because at some point there has to be an eval statement, and if the user changes the eval to an echo, they get all of your code in the browser.

And here is a [bunch of people who agree with me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232736/code-obfuscator-for-php).

Furthermore:

> People will offer you obfuscators, but no amount of obfuscation can prevent someone from getting at your code. None. If your computer can run it, or in the case of movies and music if it can play it, the user can get at it. Even compiling it to machine code just makes the job a little more difficult. If you use an obfuscator, you are just fooling yourself. Worse, you're also disallowing your users from fixing bugs or making modifications. - [Schwern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232736/code-obfuscator-for-php)

---

Now thats done:

> Bytecompiling is something completely different than encrypting. It makes the PHP code into already interpreted bytes, similar to an exe file. You can include these files just like any other php file.
>
> The byte code produced is able to be reverse engineered, but it would take lots of time and is not worth the company's time.

Check out the [byte compiler PHP extension.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bcompiler.php)

---

I'd also like to note that PHP comes with several ways of reverse engineering classes. Such as the [Reflection Class](http://us.php.net/manual/en/reflection.examples.php). This basically allows people to see every method, variables, and constant in each of your classes without the need for your source code.

Frankly, once someone sees the functions you use, it is pretty easy to piece it together after that.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of obfusticaters out there masquerading as encrypters.

If you really must encrypt your code use Zend.

IMHO shutting your customers out of your code is inherently evil and would rather hide some symbology in the code and sell it under a no-modify/re-sell contract. Then sue the ass off them if they try to sell it on. You could argue that encrypting your code closes down a business opportunity ;) !

C.