# Deploy PHP website to client server without showing PHP files

Tags: php, obfuscation

I asked a recent question regarding the use of readfile() for remotely executing PHP, but maybe I'd be better off setting out the problem to see if I'm thinking the wrong way about things, so here goes:

- I have a PHP website that requires users to login, includes lots of forms, database connections and makes use of $_SESSION variables to keep track of various things
- I have a potential client who would like to use the functionality of my website, but on their own server, controlled by them. They would probably want to restyle the website using content and CSS files local to their server, but that's a problem for later
- I don't want to show them my PHP code, since that's the value of what I'd be providing.

I had thought to do this with calls to include() from the client's server to mine, which at least keeps variable scope intact, but many sites (and the PHP docs) seem to recommend readfile(), file_get_contents() or similar. Ideally I'd like to have a simple wrapper file on the client's server for each "real" one on my server.

Any suggestions as to how I might accomplish what I need?

Thanks,
ColmF

Comment: If their server can `include` your files, then it might as well copy them.

Comment: PHP is an interpretive language and as such 'reads' the files and parses them. Yes it can store cached byte code in certain cases but it's not like the higher level languages that compile and work in bytecode. Check out http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/ which might do what you want. Failing that sign a contract with the company that includes clauses of not reusing your code / etc etc. That's your best protection in this case. You should also be careful though, if you're using anything under an 'open source' license your entire app may be considered open source and thus this is all moot.

Comment: @Matt: why don't post your comment as an answer? I propose it to be correct

Comment: Consider a "productized" deployment (as one option) in which the software is on hardware you lease to them. You control security and code, they get the benefit of it being onsite. Or, you could also consider compiled PHP (see: HipHop PHP or other).

Answer (score 6):

As suggested, comment posted as an answer & modified a touch

PHP is an interpretive language and as such 'reads' the files and parses them. Yes it can store cached byte code in certain cases but it's not like the higher level languages that compile and work in bytecode. Which means that the php 'compiler' requires your actual source code to work. Check out zend.com/en/products/guard which might do what you want though I believe it means your client has to use the Zend Server.

Failing that sign a contract with the company that includes clauses of not reusing your code / etc etc. That's your best protection in this case. You should also be careful though, if you're using anything under an 'open source' license your entire app may be considered open source and thus this is all moot.

This is not a non-standard practice for many companies. I have produced software I'm particularly proud of and a company wants to use it. As they believe in their own information security for either 'personal' reasons or because they have to comply to a standard such as PCI there are times my application must run in their environments. I have offered my products as 'web services' where they query my servers with data and recieve responses. In that case my source is completely protected as this is no different than any other closed API. In every case I have licensed the copy to the client with provisions that they are not allowed to modify nor distribute it. This is a legal binding contract and completely expected from the clients side of things. Of course there were provisions that I would provide support etc etc but that's neither here nor there.

Short answers:

- Legal agreement, likely your best bet from everyone's point of view
- Zend guard like product, never used it so I can't vouch for it
- Private API but this won't really work for you as the client needs to host it

Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

If they want it wholly contained on their server then your best bet is a legal solution not a technical one.

You license the software to them and you make sure the contract states the intellectual property belongs to you and it cannot be copied/distributed etc without prior permission (obviously you'll need some better legalese than that, but you get the idea).

Answer (score 2):

Rather than remote execution, I suggest you use a PHP source protection system, such as Zend Guard, ionCube or sourceguardian.

http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/

http://www.ioncube.com/

http://www.sourceguardian.com/

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you're looking for a way to proxy your application out to a remote server (i.e.: your clients). To use something like `readfile()` on the client's site is fine, but you're still going to need multiple scripts on their end. Basically, `readfile` scrapes what's available at a particular file path or URL and pipes it to the end user. So if I were to do `readfile('google.com')`, it would output the source code for Google's homepage.

Assuming you don't just want to have a dummy form on your clients' sites, you're going to need to have some code hanging out on their end. The code is going to have to intercept the form submissions (so you'll need a URL parameter on the page you're scraping with `readfile` to tell your code that the form submission URL is your client's site and not your own). *This* page (the form submission handler page) will need to make calls back to your own site. Think something like this:

```
readfile("https://your.site/whatever?{$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']}");
```

Your site is then going to process the response and then pass everything back to your clients' sites.

Hopefully I've gotten you on the right path. Let me know if I was unclear; I realize this is a lot of info.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to have a hard time with this unless you want some kind of funny wrapper that does `curl` type requests to your server.  Especially when it comes to handling things like sessions and cookies.

Are you sure a [PHP obfuscator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232736/code-obfuscator-for-php) wouldn't be sufficient for what you are doing?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hosting it yourself, why not do what most php applications do and simply distribute the program to your client with an auto-update feature? Hosting it yourself is complicated, from management of websites to who is paying for the hosting.

If you don't want it to be distributed, then find a pre-written license that allows you to do this. If you can't find one then it's time to talk to a lawyer.

Answer (score -1):

You can't stop them from seeing your code.  You can make it very hard for them to understand your code, which is a good second best.  See our [SD PHP Obfuscator](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Obfuscators/PHPObfuscator.html) for a tool that will scramble the identifiers and the whitespacing in the code, making it much more difficult to understand.