# PHP code security

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Code obfuscator for php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232736/code-obfuscator-for-php)

Hi,

Is it possible to encode all php code before uploading to someone server?

Actually I want to encode my php code so that no one can use without my permission...

Comment: duplicate. please use search function

Comment: You could use something like: http://www.ioncube.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can put it into a folder where none of the other users have access to. If you're not an admin, but others are, you have little chance for that, though.
@other answers: Obfuscation is not encryption. Obfuscated code is still code and can be used somewhere else...

Answer (score 0):

Read about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscated_code

And think about http://www.zend.com/products/guard/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a source code obfuscator. As php is a scripting language you can not upload pre-compiled code.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ioncube Encoder. http://www.ioncube.com/