# to encrypt php or make it "call home"

Tags: php, security, encryption, drm, ioncube

I have a simple php script and want to protect it.

I'm ruling out ioncube as they'll hack it anyway and it'll increase my customer support.

I'm hearing about making the script "call home".  Is that an alternative or is this the same as ioncube and similar encrypting software?

If this is a viable alternative, is there software or scripting that i can buy or learn to code to use this technique?

if calling home isn't the best answer, what is a better alternative for securing php scripts.

thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Probably worth looking at this question on PHP obfuscation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232736/code-obfuscator-for-php

Answer (score 7):

If this PHP code is being distributed, what is there to stop someone from removing the *call home* code?

Protect your code through legal means instead.

Answer (score 2):

You may try to obfuscate the script but *the real fix* to this problem is by contract (that is, legal means as suggested by alex).

Make the buyer of your script to sign (or otherwise legally accept) an agreement/contract/license that says what you want them to do with your script. If you don't trust them to follow the agreement, do not transfer a copy of your source to them.

Otherwise, you're practically trying to invent a DRM system, which by definition does not exists. (For example: [Playing MP3 songs without disclosing the path of the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544606/playing-mp3-songs-without-disclosing-the-path-of-the-file))

Comment: thanks for your thoughts on this.  The more i research...the more it looks like a futile attempt to try and secure.         thanks again