# Add non removable footer credit

Tags: javascript, footer

I want to make an non removable footer for my website template .I googled for this and i came across an blog article http://keyyard.blogspot.in/2013/08/how-to-add-non-removable-credit-link-in_11.html 
but it is not working for me .
please give me a solution to make it work , how to apply this code to make it work .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359560/non-removable-copyright-text-in-footer i guess there is no way to do it, but you can make it little harder... check answers related to js solutions...

Comment: had you inlcude jquery lib in your code

Comment: its working but the problem is that , it is redirecting though there is no change in the credits done or noone have deleted it .....
What to do ?
Please try this code and give some solution

Comment: http://themedaddy.net/lets-learn-to-protect-your-work-with-non-removable-credit-links/ check out this

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

add these line in your `<head>` section

Comment: its working but the problem is that , it is redirecting though there is no change in the credits done or noone have deleted it .....
What to do ?
Please try this code and give some solution