# Minify/obfuscate mix of PHP and Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, obfuscation

My project consists of javascripts of two different types:

1. External regular .js files.
2. `<script>` code embedded into PHP code, some parts of javascript are generated from PHP, like:

`var a = <?php echo Res::a; ?>;`

Now I want to obfuscate/minify the whole project: both external and embedded javascripts and PHP itself. Unfortunately, all tools I've seen work with single .js files.

Comment: Obfocusing/minifying PHP is meaningless. If your project is open to the public, why minify it? If it's not... why minify it?

Comment: [Check out this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232736/code-obfuscator-for-php) too see why obfuscation is pointless in any language.

Comment: @noober To clarify, I flagged the below post about product placement on the site. I also have no affiliation to the good people at Stack Overflow except I value the contribution to the web development community they have created. I believe this question has potential merit if it's re-worded to something like: "how do I use google closure compiler for inline JS"

Comment: @GeorgeReith For security, yes minification is basically pointless, however you can affect network and cpu performance via obfuscating/minifing. You can also streamline your development process by using inline comments as documentation and then removing those comments automatically via minification.

Comment: @Jasper Indeed but I was referring to obfuscation not minification. They aren't the same thing.

Comment: @GeorgeReith No they aren't the same, but `obfuscation` still decreases the overall size of the file by shortening variable names.

Comment: @Noober: you were right, this got closed by SO's apparant policy that seems to be focused on killing dicussions about tools.  I think this is a huge loss of utility by SO for programmers, who live and die by the tools they use.

Answer (score 2):

I think this issue if too specific to be answered with a single all-purpose tool.

A method to to it could be to use placeholder in your Javascript to replace PHP code.

```
var a = PHP_SOURCE_1;
```

Minify your javascript, using a js minifier such as Yui Compressor http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/ Then replace the placeholders by the original PHP source.

Ideally in order to properly minify your javascript code, you'll need to externalize your embedded scripts.

Answer (score 1):

> Now I want to obfuscate/minify the whole project: both external and
>   embedded javascripts and PHP itself. Unfortunately, all tools I've
>   seen work with single .js files.

Try [VarHammer JS obfuscator](http://www.varhammer.com)