# How do i write(encrypt) my php code like this

Tags: php, zend-studio

I recently used **[ShowMyCode](http://showmycode.com)** to deZend an old script to know how it works but after dezend, all of the 1000 lines appeared like this

```
function s65615il8e( $IlbXmxb915, $B94omi07x1 = 0, $i4ss65VOR0 = 0 )
{
$JleV65B6RB = array( "1276" => "period", "4126" => "V2_HASH" );
if ( 0 < $B94omi07x1 || 0 < $i4ss65VOR0 )
{
    return substr( $JleV65B6RB[$IlbXmxb915], $B94omi07x1, $i4ss65VOR0 );
}
return $JleV65B6RB[$IlbXmxb915];
}

function e4l9roibmi( $xolsL1jB0i, $dBXj7eREB6 = 0, $oR609Xb5oV = 0 )
{
$wewOBeEdoe = array( "4126" => "B8REXV4YAS6A9WVBNFEV", "1276" => "76GDKGBBKZRJ597W8F7T" );
if ( 0 < $dBXj7eREB6 || 0 < $oR609Xb5oV )
{
    return substr( $wewOBeEdoe[$xolsL1jB0i], $dBXj7eREB6, $oR609Xb5oV );
}
return $wewOBeEdoe[$xolsL1jB0i];
}
```

as you can see its completely unreadable,

**what is this method called and how can i encrypt my php code like that**

Comment: Any comment from the person who gave the down-vote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the idea of obfuscation is making code unreadable.

so this probably isn't what you want. but here's the code de-obfuscated

```
function function1( $var1, $var2 = 0, $var3 = 0 ) {
    $array1 = array( "1276" => "period", "4126" => "V2_HASH" );
    if ( 0 < $var2 || 0 < $var3 ) {
        return substr( $array1[$var1], $var2, $var3 );
    }
    return $array1[$var1];
}

function function2( $var1, $var2 = 0, $var3 = 0 ) {
    $array1 = array( "4126" => "B8REXV4YAS6A9WVBNFEV", "1276" => "76GDKGBBKZRJ597W8F7T" );
    if ( 0 < $var2 || 0 < $var3 ) {
        return substr( $array1[$var1], $var2, $var3 );
    }
    return $array1[$var1];
}
```

there's no what of knowing what the old function/variable names where. but it's much easier to read what they are doing now. hope that helps!

Comment: thank you, but isn't there a way to automatically do this, i mean changing all "s65615il8e"s to "function1" for example instead of using replace-all in text editors

Comment: yes. google php deobfuscation.
i personally like the eval hook method
http://php-security.org/2010/05/13/article-decoding-a-user-space-encoded-php-script/

Answer (score 2):

This is called **obfuscation**.

I can tell you this: don't do it.

It is quite easy to revert. Way easier than C++ - or any truely compiled language for that mather. You only fool yourself with this technique.

If you want to do it nevertheless, take a look at this: [Is there a code obfuscator for PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232736/code-obfuscator-for-php)

Comment: thank you, do you know which obfuscation methode this one (my code on above) is using

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a PHP obfuscator.
Look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232736/code-obfuscator-for-php) for more information.

Comment: thank you, do you know which obfuscation methode this one (my code on above) is using