# Secure PHP code on IIS

Tags: php, iis, obfuscation, code-access-security

My web application is going to be installed at the customer's IIS7 server. The application is built in PHP and MySQL and is responsible for synchonizing data among the mobile devices of multiple users. Each user may send a request to the IIS7 server and receive updated data. Every company will have an instance of the web application installed at a proprietary server.

I am interested in preventing someone who might have access to the PHP code of my web application (i.e. system administrator) from stealing or altering the code. Do you know of any way to achieve this? Is there anything similar to obfuscation for PHP?

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232736/code-obfuscator-for-php?rq=1

Comment: Nothing very secure - you could try ioncude, but if this is going to run on iis c# would have been easier to secure