# Obfuscation - Is it foolproof way to make php code unreadable?

Tags: php

I am planning to obfuscate my php code, so as to make it unreadable ! Is it the foolproof way to make as such, or is there any method so that another user cannot view my php code ?

Comment: It is never foolproof. Someone with enough time will always be able to deobfuscate it.

Comment: Where do you want to obfsuscate it ? Php is a server-side langage, usually...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Code obfuscator for php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232736/code-obfuscator-for-php)

Comment: If they can read your PHP when you don't want them to, you have far more significant problems. Suggest you google Obfuscation Security, you'll find plenty of good arguments against this fallacy.

Answer (score -3):

There are so many awesome tools are there for encoding PHP codes . You can use below links

http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/

http://www.ioncube.com/php_encoder.php

Comment: These are not "foolproof".

Comment: Not a good answer in any respect, you've earned a rare mark down.