# Ioncube - PHP code obfuscation without encoding

Tags: php, obfuscation, ioncube

Is there a way to obfuscate PHP code with Ioncube without encoding it?

I.e. the code is just obfuscated and it can be executed without the ioncube loader?

I am not 100% sure but I remember it was possible with an old version of Ioncube and now (v. 8.3.2) I can't find the way to do it: I still have an obfuscate option but it seems it always work *in addition* to encoding

Comment: Also, [any obfuscated code can be decompiled](http://stackoverflow.com/a/232767/247893).

Comment: I know that obfuscated code can be decompiled and ye I did search for alternatives, however my question was related to Ioncube, it seems to me it was possible in old versions and now I can't find the way to do it.

Comment: @Eugenio Might be a good idea to add that into your question, and say what versions it works with and what versions it doesn't.

Comment: Do you insist on IonCube or is any solution that obfuscates without encoding appropriate?

Comment: @IraBaxter if it's not possible with ioncube I'll evaluate other options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it is not possible and it has never been possible to obfuscate only: http://forum.ioncube.com/viewtopic.php?p=10797#10797