# How to protect my code written in php which is to be installed on local server of a user

Tags: php, encryption

I want to protect my code in such a way that user should not copy and use or edit easily . As i know i can not protect 100%. I should put my code on user's local machine. So i am worried. While searching i got reference for [ZendGaurd](http://www.zend.com/products/guard), but right now i can not invest that much in this?

Can somebody suggest me how can i do it? Is there any other way around?

Can i keep few files like `configuration.php` or `stylesheet` on my online server ?

Comment: Does the user have access to your server? If not they cannot copy your PHP code.

Comment: Read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232736/is-there-a-code-obfuscator-for-php

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions: Thank you very much. I think i will get the solution here. Thanks.