# Change user password automatically in every month and send password to particular email

Tags: php, laravel

I am user `Laravel 6x` and i have developed a `School Management System` for client and he don't want it to online. He just want to install it to their office computer. So now i am looking for way that i can change the admin password in every month and i get that new password through email, then i send it to my client on order to control my application. And i want to have a control on my application that he can not see application source code.

So how i can control my application?????

Comment: If you develop an application for a client and he compensates you for your work its not longer your application anymore.

Comment: but what if our agreement are in monthly based. He will pay money to me on every month

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do this using something like AnyDesk or TeamViewer. 
But still, you can't protect your source code from the user since code is in customer's machine but you can request from your customer to host it by telling some benefits.
to schedule the monthly you can refer this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling)
to [email](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail) sending you can use this. yet you need to do some adjustments to work this in local machine and I think best way to do this hosting and if you're developing software for client after payment it's becoming a customer's property yet if you want to protect your code from leaking misusing or reusing you can get signed agreement from customer that says those things illegal or something yet I think the best solution is hosting it's reliable 
and **if your payment coming monthly basis you should host your product by your money so you can protect code if your customer stop getting your service you can just stop giving them services but if the files in there machine it's going to be a big problem for you because they can copy everything and use them** and tell your customer for maintenance and other security reasons you can't host it in local machine

Comment: Ok i understand. Thank you for your suggestion. @Thalinda Bandara

Answer (score 0):

You want online access, your customer wants an offline solution (your customer appears to be considerably reasonable -- why use something with online access, perhaps back doors and probably security issues if you can do it online -- NOI). Either side has to withdraw their constraints or you will lose a contract.

If you want to assert that you receive your monthly lease, implement some licensing mechanism which requires the user to pay to extend the service. On return, he will get some token which must be passed to the system. No valid token, no running program.

Concerning your 2nd question: If you want to make sure that decoding your source code is most inconvenient, you might consider to look out for some [code obfuscator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232736/is-there-a-code-obfuscator-for-php/232767).